Reading multiple excels into R where data doesn't start in A1 cell
I have numerous Excel workbooks which contain data in cells B10:N13 and look like the below

I would like to read in all the excel files from my filepath taking the column names from B10:N10 and the % Positive data from B13:N13. I would also like to create a date field using the date variable from the B2 cell. I would then append the data to end up with one dataframe that would look something like this (obviously and R dataframe, not an excel table, just using excel to demonstrate)

I know how to get a list of all the Excels from my file path
# Define the folder path containing Excel files
folder_path <- "O:/Surveillance/3. Dissemination/Reports/Resp data/Respiratory data/"

# Get a list of Excel files in the folder
file_list <- list.files(path = folder_path, pattern = '*.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

But I don't know how to write a function to loop through all of the excels and pull this information and bind them together. I did find a messy way to extract the information I wanted with just one excel but I'm sure there's a much neater way to do this and to then put it into a function/loop.
# Read in data from table in Excel
test <- read_excel("O:/Surveillance/3. Dissemination/Reports/Resp data/Respiratory data/Respiratory summary WE 2022-07-03.xlsx", 
                   sheet = 'Summary', 
                   range = 'B10:N13')

# Keep only the % Positive row
test_filtered <- test[3, ]

# Extract the date from cell B1
date_cell <- read_excel("O:/Surveillance/3. Dissemination/Reports/Resp data/Respiratory data/Respiratory summary WE 2022-07-03.xlsx",
                        sheet = 'Summary',
                        range = 'B1:B1',
                        col_names = FALSE)

date <- date_cell[1, 1]  

# Add date column to other data and rename
test_filtered <- cbind(date = date, test_filtered) |> 
  rename('date' = '...1') 

# Extract date portion of string
test_filtered <- test_filtered %>%
  mutate(date = sub("^.*\\b(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})$", "\\1", date))


Would love some guidance. Please be kind, I am still learning :)

I ended up finding my own solution for anyone who is looking to do something similar
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(plotly)

# Define the folder path containing Excel files
folder_path <- "My_folder"

# Get a list of Excel files in the folder
file_list <- list.files(path = folder_path, pattern = '*.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

# Define a function to extract the desired data from each Excel file
extract_data <- function(file_path) {
  # Read the Excel file
  workbook <- readxl::read_excel(file_path, col_names = FALSE)
  
  # Extract column names from B10:N10
  column_names <- unlist(workbook[10, 2:14])
  
  # Extract data from B13:N13
  data_values <- unlist(workbook[13, 2:14])
  
  # Extract date from cell B1
  date_string <- workbook[1, 2]
  date_value <- str_extract(date_string, "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}") 
  
  # Create a data frame with column names, data values, and date
  data_frame <- data.frame(matrix(data_values, nrow = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, column_names)))
  data_frame$date <- date_value
  
  return(data_frame)
}

# Apply the extract_data function to each file and combine the results
combined_old <- purrr::map_dfr(file_list, extract_data)


This is how I would do it with purrr::map() and dplyr package. I took some files from the readxl package as example. map() allows to repeat the same operations on every element (xl) of a list (list of filenames). Those operations are read_excel() and dplyr::mutate() a specific cell (adding a column). The list of dataframe are merged with purrr::list_rbind()
I think that you will be able to adapt your code with it :)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

# Listing files
# Examples from the readxl package, could be from a specific folder. Choosing 3
list_of_xl= list.files( system.file("extdata",package="readxl"), full.names = TRUE )[c(2,4,6)]
# Alternative in a more realistic case:
#list_of_xl = list.files("MyExcelFolder", full.names = TRUE)

merged = list_of_xl %>% 
  map( \(xl) read_excel(xl) %>%
         #Adding  the cell A2 as a column of every file. Specifying "text" for an easy bind
         mutate(A2Cell = read_excel(xl, range="A2:A2", col_names = FALSE , col_types = "text")) 
  ) %>% 
  list_rbind()
#> New names:
#> New names:
#> New names:
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`

merged
#> # A tibble: 172 × 14
#>    name      value A2Cell$...1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>    <chr>     <chr> <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Name      Clip… Name                NA          NA           NA          NA  
#>  2 Species   pape… Name                NA          NA           NA          NA  
#>  3 Approx d… 39083 Name                NA          NA           NA          NA  
#>  4 Weight i… 0.9   Name                NA          NA           NA          NA  
#>  5 <NA>      <NA>  5.1                  5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#>  6 <NA>      <NA>  5.1                  4.9         3            1.4         0.2
#>  7 <NA>      <NA>  5.1                  4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#>  8 <NA>      <NA>  5.1                  4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#>  9 <NA>      <NA>  5.1                  5           3.6          1.4         0.2
#> 10 <NA>      <NA>  5.1                  5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
#> # ℹ 162 more rows
#> # ℹ 7 more variables: Species <chr>, `Lots of people` <chr>, ...2 <chr>,
#> #   ...3 <chr>, ...4 <chr>, ...5 <chr>, ...6 <chr>

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks heaps but I couldn't get it to work for me but I found my own solution.
